# Which is better approach to send push notification in Kuzzle using hooks or subscription?

Tags: kuzzle

I’m using Kuzzle as backend for my realtime chat application.
What is the better approach to sending push notification when user is offline in a mobile chat app?

**1. Using custom plugin hooks**

```
// check for every message in chat 
this.hooks = {
  'document:afterCreate': (request) => {

    if (request.input.resource.collection == 'messages') {

      let message = request.input.body;
      this.context.accessors.sdk.document.get('now', 'user_sessions', message.otherUserId).then((userSession) => {

        if (!userSession._source.isOnline) {
          userSession._source.devices.forEach(device => {
            // send push notification
          });
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Subscription per user for all users after the Kuzzle server start-up**

```
const app = new Backend('kuzzlebackend')

app.start()
  .then(async () => {
    // Application started

    // Loops through all users and adds their subscriptions to Kuzzle

    foreach(user in users) {
      app.sdk.realtime.subscribe('now', 'messages', { ‘otherUserId' : user._id }, async (notification: Notification) => {

        this.context.accessors.sdk.document.get('now', 'user_sessions', user._id).then((userSession) => {

        if (!userSession._source.isOnline) {
          userSession._source.devices.forEach(device => {
            // send push notification
          });
        }
      })
      })
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [hook mechanism](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/develop-on-kuzzle/event-system/#hooks) on the [generic:document:afterWrite](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/framework/events/generic-document/#generic-document-afterwrite) event to send notification to offline users when a new message is created.

This event will be triggered every time a document is written with one of the Document controller action, and for the `m*` action family it you will able to process documents in bulk instead of one by one.